# Why doesn't other characters appear?

Tags: assembly, nasm

I have function `print` that takes byte at register `dl` and prints it to console as character. I'm putting some bytes into memory and then moving from that memory spot to `dl` and calling `print` function but the second time I call it, it doesn't print character (first time works fine). I am using Windows 10 and assembling to 64bit.

I want this to print `AB` but only `A` prints

```
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp

    mov     DWORD [rbp-4], 'ABCD'
    mov     DWORD [rbp-8], 'XYZH'


    mov     dl, BYTE [rbp-4]
    call print

    mov     dl, BYTE [rbp-3]
    call print

    mov     eax, 0
    pop     rbp
    ret
```

and the print function in defined like this:

```
print:
    lea rax, var
    mov BYTE [rax], dl

    sub     rsp, 8+8+8+32
    mov     ecx, -11
    call    GetStdHandle

    mov     rcx, rax
    mov     rdx, var
    mov     r8,  1
    lea     r9,  [rsp-16]
    mov     QWORD [rsp-56], 0
    call    WriteConsoleA


    add     rsp, 8+8+32+8
    ret
```

`var` is defined like this in data section: `var:  db 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `call print` instruction overwrites the characters! You need to adjust `RSP`.
If you don't lower the stackpointer, then the CPU will put the return address from the `call` instruction right where you wrote your characters.

```
push    rbp
mov     rbp, rsp
sub     rsp, 8

mov     DWORD [rbp-4], 'ABCD'
mov     DWORD [rbp-8], 'XYZH'


mov     dl, BYTE [rbp-4]
call print

mov     dl, BYTE [rbp-3]
call print

mov     eax, 0
mov     rsp, rbp
pop     rbp
ret
```